When creating an ArCore session, a black screen appears instead of the camera image
I'm new to creating applications for Android, and even more so to working with ArCore. For now, I just need to connect to the ArCore application in such a way that when I go to the camera section, the camera opens, the image from the phone camera. As far as I understand, when creating a session, ArCore should automatically connect the device’s camera, but for some reason I get a black screen. If someone could tell me what my mistake is, I would be very grateful. I apologize if my question turns out to be something very basic, this is my first time connecting ArCore. If anything, my device supports ArCore, and there are no errors anywhere in the logs related to the fact that it is not possible to create a session.
Here is my code for AcoreActivity
class ArcoreActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private var mUserRequestedInstall = true
    private var mSession: Session? = null
    private lateinit var surfaceView: SurfaceView
    //private val myTextView: TextView = findViewById(R.id.my_text_view)

    @SuppressLint("MissingInflatedId")
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_arcore)
        surfaceView = findViewById(R.id.surfaceView)
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        if (!CameraPermissionHelper.hasCameraPermission(this)) {
            CameraPermissionHelper.requestCameraPermission(this)
            //myTextView.text = "1"
            return
        }
        try {
            if (mSession == null) {
                when (ArCoreApk.getInstance().requestInstall(this, mUserRequestedInstall)) {
                    ArCoreApk.InstallStatus.INSTALLED -> {
                        mSession = Session(this)
                        createSession()
                    }

                    ArCoreApk.InstallStatus.INSTALL_REQUESTED -> {
                        mUserRequestedInstall = false
                        //myTextView.text = "2"
                        return
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (e: UnavailableUserDeclinedInstallationException) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "TODO: handle exception " + e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            //myTextView.text = "3"
            return
        }
        try {
            mSession?.resume()
            surfaceView.holder.addCallback(object : SurfaceHolder.Callback {
                override fun surfaceCreated(holder: SurfaceHolder) {
                    mSession?.setCameraTextureName(holder.surface.hashCode())
                }

                override fun surfaceChanged(holder: SurfaceHolder, format: Int, width: Int, height: Int) {}

                override fun surfaceDestroyed(holder: SurfaceHolder) {}
            })
        } catch (e: CameraNotAvailableException) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Камера не доступна", e)
            //myTextView.text = "4"
            mSession = null
            return
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
        requestCode: Int,
        permissions: Array<String>,
        grantResults: IntArray
    ) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
        if (!CameraPermissionHelper.hasCameraPermission(this)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Camera permission is needed to run this application", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show()
            //myTextView.text = "5"
            if (!CameraPermissionHelper.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this)) {
                CameraPermissionHelper.launchPermissionSettings(this)
               // myTextView.text = "6"
            }
            finish()
        }
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        mSession?.pause()
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        mSession?.close()
        mSession = null
    }

    // Verify that ARCore is installed and using the current version.
    fun isARCoreSupportedAndUpToDate(): Boolean {
        return when (ArCoreApk.getInstance().checkAvailability(this)) {
            ArCoreApk.Availability.SUPPORTED_INSTALLED -> true
            ArCoreApk.Availability.SUPPORTED_APK_TOO_OLD, ArCoreApk.Availability.SUPPORTED_NOT_INSTALLED -> {
                try {
                    // Request ARCore installation or update if needed.
                    when (ArCoreApk.getInstance().requestInstall(this, true)) {
                        ArCoreApk.InstallStatus.INSTALL_REQUESTED -> {
                            Log.i(TAG, "ARCore installation requested.")
                            false
                        }
                        ArCoreApk.InstallStatus.INSTALLED -> true
                    }
                } catch (e: UnavailableException) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "ARCore not installed", e)
                    false
                }
            }
            ArCoreApk.Availability.UNSUPPORTED_DEVICE_NOT_CAPABLE ->
                // This device is not supported for AR.
                false

            ArCoreApk.Availability.UNKNOWN_CHECKING -> {
                // ARCore is checking the availability with a remote query.
                // This function should be called again after waiting 200 ms to determine the query result.
                false
            }
            ArCoreApk.Availability.UNKNOWN_ERROR, ArCoreApk.Availability.UNKNOWN_TIMED_OUT -> {
                // There was an error checking for AR availability. This may be due to the device being offline.
                // Handle the error appropriately.
                false
            }
        }
    }
    private fun createSession() {
        // Create a new ARCore session.
        mSession = Session(this)

        // Create a session config.
        val config = Config(mSession)

        // Do feature-specific operations here, such as enabling depth or turning on
        // support for Augmented Faces.

        // Configure the session.
        mSession!!.configure(config)
    }

    fun maybeEnableArButton() {
        ArCoreApk.getInstance().checkAvailabilityAsync(this) { availability ->
            if (availability.isSupported) {
                //
            } else {
                //
            }
        }
    }
}

And here I call ArcoreActivity from MainActivity:
    private fun openCameraFragment() {
        startActivity(Intent(this, ArcoreActivity::class.java))
        finish()
    }

